# A For Loop to Multiply a Number Repeatedly Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to start with `x = 100`, then multiply it by 1.1 and get the result (110 in this case) then do the same again with the result.

I want the output to look something like

1.) 100
2.) 110
3.) 121
.
.
.
150.) Result.

I have no idea how to do this; I tried defining `x = 100` and `y = 1.1x` and setting `x` equal to `y` at the end of each loop, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Are you defining them inside or outside the loop? Also, it should be "y= 1.1*x".  If you could add your code it would be easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: if the important thing is finding the result, know that this is what powers are for. In your case, it would be 1.1**149 * 100. If the problem is coding it look at the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
x = 100
for i in range(150):
    line = str(i+1) + '.) ' + str(x)
    print(line)
    x = 1.1*x
```

Comment: `x = x * 1.1` could also be written as `x *= 1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `y` variable, you can simply reasign the new value to x at every iteration of the loop.

```
x = 100
for i in xrange(150):
    print x
    x = x * 1.1
```